# Executemany command on linux box

Tags: linux, python-3.x, oracle, pyodbc

```
     if platform[0:3]=='lin':
        oracledriver = '{Oracle}'
    elif platform[0:3]=='win':
        oracledriver = 'Oracle in OraClient12home2'        
    oracledbq = 'uat:1521/uat'
    oracleuid = 'user'
    oraclepwd = 'pwd'  
    oracleConn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=oracledriver, UID=oracleuid, PWD=oraclepwd, DBQ=oracledbq)
    cursor = oracleConn.cursor() 
    cursor.fast_executemany = True  
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO matrix_new (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",tuples)
```

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

I am trying to batch insert about 30000 rows. I even tried to use insert in chunks of 100 but still this failed.

The code works fine on windows machine. Not exactly sure what is missing.

Currently using pyodbc, oracle server.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? If it's a CSV file, you could use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: No code?  How did you setup your cursor?  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Comments in https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/src/errors.cpp that may apply. Line 334: "This only happens using unixODBC.  (Haven't tried iODBC yet.)  Either the driver or the driver manager is buggy and has signaled a fault without recording error information." Also, line 236: "If the function fails, for example, if it runs out of memory, zero is returned." On Oracle check the trace logs. This gives the location: `SELECT VALUE FROM V$DIAG_INFO WHERE NAME = 'Default Trace File';`

Comment: 1. Added the pre-cursor code to show how cursor is setup.
2. I am building a table in python and trying to insert it.